# Nightwatch with Chromedriver does not exit after assertions

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, selenium-server

I have an issue whereby Nightwatch is not exiting after all the assertions have passed. The execution seems to freeze and never exits despite the chrome driver being closed.

The versions are as follows:

```
chromedriver (headless): 2.41.0
selenium-server: 3.14.0
nightwatch: 1.0.9
```

The firefox driver is working correctly.

The contents of runner.js are below:

```
// 1. start the dev server using production config
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'testing';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const DevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');

const webpackConfig = require('../../build/webpack.prod.conf');
const devConfigPromise = require('../../build/webpack.dev.conf');

let server;

devConfigPromise.then((devConfig) => {
  const devServerOptions = devConfig.devServer;
  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
  server = new DevServer(compiler, devServerOptions);
  const port = devServerOptions.port;
  const host = devServerOptions.host;
  return server.listen(port, host);
})
  .then(() => {
  // 2. run the nightwatch test suite against it
  // to run in additional browsers:
  //    1. add an entry in test/e2e/nightwatch.conf.js under "test_settings"
  //    2. add it to the --env flag below
  // or override the environment flag, for example: `npm run e2e -- --env chrome,firefox`
  // For more information on Nightwatch's config file, see
  // http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#settings-file
    let opts = process.argv.slice(2);
    if (opts.indexOf('--config') === -1) {
      opts = opts.concat(['--config', 'test/e2e/nightwatch.conf.js']);
    }
    if (opts.indexOf('--env') === -1) {
      opts = opts.concat(['--env', 'chrome']);
    }

    const spawn = require('cross-spawn');
    const runner = spawn('./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch', opts, { stdio: 'inherit' });

    runner.on('exit', (code) => {
      server.close();
      process.exit(code);
    });

    runner.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(`About to exit with code: ${err}`);
      server.close();
      throw err;
    });
  });
```

The contents of the nightwatch.conf.js is below:

```
require('babel-register');
const config = require('../../config');

// http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#settings-file
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['test/e2e/specs'],
  output_folder: 'test/e2e/reports',
  custom_assertions_path: ['test/e2e/custom-assertions'],

  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: require('selenium-server').path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      'webdrive.gecko.driver': require('geckodriver').path,
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path,
    },
  },
  test_settings: {
    default: {
      selenium_port: 5555,
      selenium_host: 'localhost',
      silent: true,
      globals: {
        devServerURL: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || config.dev.port}`,
        serverUrl: '[server url]',
      },
    },

    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
          args: [
            '--headless', '--no-sandbox',
          ],
        },
      },
    },

    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
          args: [
            '-headless',
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I haven't been able to find a solution so far.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using different port settings for test and selenium?

Comment: That's a fair point. Unfortunately once I updated them to match the problem still persists.

Comment: I would try a few things: restart your machine, if that doesn't work(itdw), re-install chromedriver. itdw re-install the selenium jar, itdw confirm that you have the latest version of java, restart your machine again. If none of those work, I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're calling browser.end() as the last step of each test.

Second, Nightwatch 1.0+ is still in beta. I'd try version 0.9.21, that's what most people are still using. File a bug against version 1.09 if 0.9.21 works.